# Visual Studio:Setting Project Property Values from a central file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am looking for a general way to make a project inherit it's properties from a parent solution in Visual Studio 2010.

What i want is a project properties file like an xml that can be used for every type of project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Visual Studio Project Templates](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.carlosag.net/articles/create-vs-template&ei=Hm7VTqOMCoaIhQfAsPRS&usg=AFQjCNEf40cAU08TuekxUJM-RQsoLBv-wQ&sig2=WR80Gq_6mnuzZeStidjYcQ) and it'll add it in your New Project dialog.